# How to create a trigger, by extracting form another column in the time of INSERT in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Consider Below:

Table:
`CREATE TABLE test1 (TID CHAR(8), TNAME VARCHAR2(30));`

While Inserting the TNAME, I want to generate TID as per TNAME.
Example: *TNAME = Sports Bike TID = SB*
If TNAME contain 1 word then first 4 letter.
If it contains 2 Word then first 2 letter from the first word and later two letter from the 2nd word like that.

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: IMHO you can do that in the server side languages

Comment: i want it in sql, PL/SQL

Comment: use [before insert trigger](https://www.mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-plsql-before-insert-trigger-example/)

Comment: Your example doesn't match your description; shouldn't that be `SpBi`? But more importantly, isn't this going to produce a lot of clashes? What's the point of the TID and what will it be used for? This seems to be more about the logic for generating that value, in PL/SQL or SQL, than about a trigger per se.

Comment: TID should probably be a standard `varchar2`, not `char`. Why pad `SB`  (or `SpBi`) to 8 characters?

Comment: Yes, I do need the logic. How to get that SPBI value.

Comment: Forget about the CHAR(8), Ok. Provide me the logic. That is more important. @WilliamRobertson

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER aaa
  BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSTR(:new.TNAME, ' ') > 0 THEN
:new.TID = SUBSTR(:new.TNAME, 1, 2) + SUBSTR(:new.TNAME, INSTR(:new.TNAME, ' ') + 1, 2)
ELSE
:new.TID = SUBSTR(TNAME, 1, 4)
ENDIF;
END;
```